# How can I disable 'exclusive mode' in ALSA?

Tags: audio, alsa

I am running Arch Linux and using ALSA direct for audio (i.e. no Pulseaudio). I had a problem with a game I am running (Divinity: Original Sin), where I was getting no audio from the in-game videos. It appears this is being caused by the game taking exclusive control of the sound card when it starts up, which apparently locks out even its own videos from the audio.

This seems to be the case, because if I try to use another audio app after I start the game (e.g. Rhythmbox), I also get no sound from that. However, if I start playing something in Rhythmbox *before* I load up the game, then the sound in the in-game videos does work (i.e. the game presumably can't obtain the exclusive access).

This is clearly a bug in the game, in that it is locking its own videos out of the sound device. However, is there anything I can do in the ALSA configuration to disable the 'exclusive mode'? I want all my apps to be multiplexing and don't want any to be able to monopolize the sound card in that way.

Comment: Is the OS user member of the `audio` group?

Comment: @Krackout the user running the game was a member of the audio group. I just tried removing them, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: Write a script that plays a little bit of silence while starting the game.

Comment: @CL. I am sure that probably will work, as a workaround. However, I am still curious as to whether there is some method to prevent any application from being able to obtain an exclusive 'lock' over ALSA.

Comment: It would be possible to redefine the `hw` device, but then you'd also have to redefine all the other devices that use `hw`.

Comment: @CL. What does the `hw` device do?

Comment: It defines what a device name like `hw:0` actually does. I'd guess the game tries `hw` first to avoid any latencies due to the mixing done by the `default` device.

Comment: @CL. Ok, that's interesting. Thanks for the info :)